# JBOSS 6.2 - New missing/unsatisfied dependencies (for mysql driver)

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jboss, jboss6.x

I have setup database with reg schema & downloaded JOBSS 6.2 EAP. I wanted to 
make some configuration for JNDI so I made some changes in standalone.xml

standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc.ds.reg.nontx" pool-name="java:jboss/jdbc.ds.reg.nontx_Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reg</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>root</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

I also added module.xml & mysql-connector-java-5.1.28 in 
%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql folder

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

but I am still getting this error while starting jboss

> New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql
>   (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.driver-demander."java:jboss/jdbc.ds.reg.nontx", service
>   jboss.data-source."java:jboss/jdbc.ds.reg.nontx"]

Comment: Do you have driver named mysql defined in `<drivers>`

Comment: I was missing that entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the drivers section as stated by the error :

> New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql
>   (missing)...

In the datasources section there should be also a drivers block

this is an example for oracle db (mysql shall follow the same pattern):

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/doxee/staging_aggregation/dbsettings" pool-name="Doxee_sa" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=p4xd1-scan2.griffon.local)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=P4CRSIPRN.griffon.local)))</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>DOXEE_SA</user-name>
                        <password>Z.3cv_7Auc</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>

                <drivers>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

and in the module.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

So as you can see

```
datasources -> datasource -> driver
```

is pointing to oracle which is defined by

```
datasources -> drivers -> driver -> name
```